# I cant export db object to other files when using mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

index.js file

```
const { getTest } = require('./function.js');
var db;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user connected');
    socket.on('test', () => {
        getTest()
    });
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('MongoDB connected');
        db = mongoose.connection.db;
        server.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error);
    });


module.exports = { db };
```

function.js file

```
const { db } = require('./index.js');

async function getTest() {
    const test = await db.collection('testing').find().toArray();
    console.log(test);
}

module.exports = { getTest };
```

I get this error

```
const test = await db.collection('testing').find().toArray();                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
```

I have tried many different methods and solutions i found but i cannot get this to work

Is there no simple way to export the db object and use that in other files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058565/cannot-read-property-collection-of-undefined-mongodb)

Comment: mongoose.connect is asynchronous, so the `module.exports` line is reached long before `db` is given a value other than undefined.